# How to set the Image of an UIImageView with the source attribute URL of a HTML <img> tag?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to set the image of an UIImageView with the contents of a img tag of a web. The HTML code is similar to this one:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; display: block; margin: auto; cursor: zoom-in;" src="https://web.whatsapp.com/pp?t=l&amp;u=34607243225%40c.us&amp;i=1449421118" width="325" height="325">
```

I tried to use SDWebImage but it is not working. So I suppose I can load a NSData with the HTML src link and decode somehow in my code.

Any tip with this issue please?

Comment: I tried pasting the url in browser, nothing comes up. So it means the image is not even there. Otherwise you could just use `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];`

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I supposed that yesterday, but it does not want to load data. So I have to figure out other solution.